# Django custom auth model

Tags: python, django, django-registration

Not sure how to name this problem, let me elaborate.
I have very old django project, been migrating it since django 1.5 or so.
It has always had class `Member`, extending `User` and has been practically used as authentication model for the app. `AUTH_USER_MODEL` was never changed, however `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL` is set to custom auth model (and it works that way).
Currently I am migrating to django 3.x and I am ran into trouble with django-registration - it used to work with `Member` set as model, but now it checks it against `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Bottom line is, I want to make it the "right" way and set proper custom model and make sure I do it right before I dig deep into it as I expect it not to be too easy.

When I simply set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to custom model, I get error `members.Member.user_ptr: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.`
When I make `Member` extend `AbstractUser` instead of `User`, I am missing id and fields as django then expects all data in single table (rather than having 2 one-to-one relationship tables).
I could somehow manually merge data into this single table, but I am not even sure if that's the right way.

What would be the best way to keep this project out of trouble for the future? How do I migrate/proceed? I am willing to get my hands dirty :-)

Comment: Check this https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2019/04/26/how-switch-custom-django-user-model-mid-project/

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to help without sample code. Otherwise

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL after you’ve created database tables is
> significantly more difficult since it affects foreign keys and
> many-to-many relationships

These articles might help you.

[Ruddra.com](https://ruddra.com/django-custom-user-migration-mid-phase-project/)

[Tobias McNulty](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2019/04/26/how-switch-custom-django-user-model-mid-project/)